# Not getting "User" option in Scope (User Settings in C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings

I need to use user settings in my projects. I have found some good example on the internet. However, I am not able to implement it in my project as I am not getting "User" option in scope field.

PF below snip.

[image: I can find Application only.]

Please let me know how I can get "User" option in scope.

Comment: Tag the question properly for better answers. It is most likely related with visual studio/project type. What version you are using? And what is the project type?

Comment: Thank you Manoj. I am using VS 2012 and WEB Project.

Comment: I have also checked in VS 2010. But I got same issue.

Comment: Pretty sure user settings don't apply to web projects.  Where would they get stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web projects don't have have a 'User' scope. If you have to manage settings for each user then you'll have to implement it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, web projects dont have the User scope for project setting.

Here is as said:

> The project system stores application settings in two XML files: an app.config file, which is created at design time when you create the first application setting; and a user.config file, which is created at run time when the user who runs the application changes the value of any user setting. Notice that changes in user settings are not written to disk unless the application specifically calls a method to do this.